# Buttons changing position on full-size

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

I'm using a flexslider, and i edited the buttons to be in the following form:
[image]

however they keep this position (which is the correct position) on window re-size. But when putting the window on full size, the button do an animation and are placed as follow:

[image]

How to fix them in the same position on full-size as it is when window is re-sized.

PS: This is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/v8hgwg8k/  if you re-size the  result window you'll notice the problem.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Mode Website Template | Home :: w3layouts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../sss/woothemes-FlexSlider-83b3cae/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../sss/woothemes-FlexSlider-83b3cae/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider(
        {
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: false
        }
    );
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.5.0
 * http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 and later license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 * 
 */
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * FONT-FACE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESETS
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flex-container a:hover,
.flex-slider a:hover,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flex-slider a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.slides,
.slides > li,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.flex-pauseplay span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * BASE STYLES
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.flexslider .slides:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .flexslider .slides {
  display: block;
}
* html .flexslider .slides {
  height: 1%;
}
.no-js .flexslider .slides > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * DEFAULT THEME
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0 0 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
}
.flex-viewport {
  max-height: 2000px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: url(Arrow-02.png);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: url(Arrow-01.png);
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev .icon-circle-arrow-left:before {content:"XXXX";}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next .icon-circle-arrow-right:before {content:"XXXX";}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f004';
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
  content: '\f003';
}
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 340px;
  margin-left: 275px;;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  background: #666;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: #8a8c8d;
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESPONSIVE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 570px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 20px;
  }
}


.flexslider{
width:700px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 200px;

}
```

Comment: could you tell me what you did for the navigation buttons, so that they appear at top of the image ?

Comment: @dreamweiver i changed the top in .flex-direction-nav... And for the left and right positioning i changed .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev and .flex-next

Comment: check this fiddle  and can you make the same edit ,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Lyngd0t0/

Comment: @dreamweiver ok give me a minute

Comment: @dreamweiver the thing is i edited it from the .css file ... How can i put the edited css file on my laptop to the external files in the jsfiddle?

Comment: do one thing, remove the `flexslider css` file from the external files entry and add your modified `css` code on the `right top` section in jsfiddle

Comment: @dreamweiver just one final thing so i can get this working... I added images as arrows to the css, how to get them in the jsfiddle?

Comment: in order to add your images, it needs to be somewhere on the net. you can do it in two ways : 1. find similiar image on net and refer that path . 2. add your image here and refer that path in your code,http://postimage.org/

Comment: @dreamweiver i used postimage and posted the llink in the css in 
content: url(http://postimg.org/image/5gdx6lbzv/)

Comment: but it didn't work, didn't i do it well?

Comment: @dreamweiver it worked, i'm just edditing the css now

Comment: @dreamweiver http://jsfiddle.net/v8hgwg8k/ this is the jsfiddle.. If you resize it you'll get the result in the 1st image above. The problem presented in the 2nd image above, is noticeable when extending the jsfiddle towards the max size

Comment: @dreamweiver thank you a lot my friend i managed to get help and fix it because of  the jsfiddle...I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your media queries; the base styles for the next/prev buttons:

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: -50px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: -50px; }
```

But, when your window is smaller then 860px, these selectors kick in:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
    .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: 570px; }
    .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: 20px; }
}
```

So remove the styles in the @media query, or move it to the base, or whatever you want ;)